# ¿Como puedo checar si un valor existe en un array antes de hacerle push en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Ok lo que quiero hacer es que antes de que mi codigo empuje el valor al array, primero verifique si ya existe dentro del array, si esto es cierto entonces evitar que el valor se ingrese en el array, y si no existe entonces empujarlo.

```
let valor = document.getElementById('valor');
let btnSubmit = document.getElementById('btn-submit');
let valores = [];

btnSubmit.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

//Checar si existe el valor en el array

  valores.push(valor.value);

//si el valor ya existe
  alert("El valor que ingresaste ya existe");
});
```

Comment: Bienvenido te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para que conozcas más acerca del sitio, así mismo leer [ask] y [mcve] para que tus respuestas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, es importante que muestres tu código de lo que haz intentado y especificar el error de tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `includes()` del prorotipo `Array`.

Un ejemplo:

```js
const myArr = [
  "el",
  "perro",
  "de",
  "san",
  "Roque",
  "no",
  "tiene"
];

const pushElementToArray = (arr, el) => {
  if(arr.includes(el)) {
    console.log(`${el} ya existe en el array`);
  } else {
    arr.push(el);
  }
}

console.log(myArr);

pushElementToArray(myArr, 'rabo'); // Añade rabo al array, ya que aun no existe
pushElementToArray(myArr, 'rabo'); // Devuelve en consola un log indicando que rabo ya existe, no lo añade al array.

console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

tendrías que recorrer el array existente y comparar con contra el valor que entra

**NOTA**: Tienes que validar primero si el array contiene elementos para recorelo asi:

`if(this.arrayexistente.length > 0)` o `if(this.arrayexistente.count> 0)`

Quedaría algo como esto:

```
if(this.arrayexistente.length > 0){
    this.arrayexistente.forEach(element => {
       if (!element === valorAComparar) {
            // Si no existe , lo agregas
       }
    });
} else {  
  // aqui realizas el primer push al array sin realizar comparación
}
```

o puedes usuar `arrayexistente.includes( 'valor a buscar' )` este arroja un true o un false dependiendo del resultados tomas la decisión de hacer el push.